# How can I print the Google Script I have written?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I want to print the Google script I have written (ultimately into a PDF) so I can send it to someone for them to look at.

I am unable to share the spreadsheet with them so I want to send it as another file but I don't want to lose the formatting. Not sure if this is possible but any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: That won’t keep the formatting and colour coding that Google shows in the script viewer :(

Comment: Print screen + paste?

Comment: Print page as PDF?

Comment: Print screen requires many print screens for long script and printing a page as a PDF only prints what is displayed by the browser, not the entire script. Thank you for the suggestions though.

Answer (score 1):

To export a static version of your code as displayed in the Apps Script Editor do the following: "Save Page As..." "Complete Webpage" on Chrome (other browsers will have corresponding method). Then share the resulting .htm file and folder. Delete all the .js files so that you don't get error messages. Done!

Here's an example folder you can download to see what the result looks like with javascript files deleted: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1eEhXJ7O7wc_uVzvzxIQ-ZpDnKA6HD_61?usp=sharing